# Traceback when updating status on twitter via Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I've been trying to post the readings from my Rpi on Twitter using `tweepy`, but first I wanted to check if `tweepy` was working properly, but it's not.

I installed the packages properly, but when I'm trying to run a simple code to post something, I got an error (Yes, I already created an app and have the 4 credentials).

The code I'm trying to run:

```
import tweepy
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
single_tweet = 'hello world'
api.update_status(single_tweet)
print "successfully Updated"
```

I got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/tweepy/api.py", line 193, in update_status
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/tweepy/binder.py", line 239, in _call
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/tweepy/binder.py", line 223, in execute
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{u'message': u'media_ids parameter is invalid.', u'code': 44}]
```

I'm runing the python code that is in the tweepy folder "oauth.py" (adding it my credentials)

```
$ sudo python oauth.py
RapiCARA
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "oauth.py", line 34, in <module>
    api.update_status(' Hello world ')
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/tweepy/api.py", line 193, in update_status
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/tweepy/binder.py", line 239, in _call
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/tweepy/binder.py", line 223, in execute
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{u'message': u'media_ids parameter is invalid.', u'code': 44}]
```

The code in that file, you can find it in its origial source: [Tweepy in GITHUB](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/examples/oauth.py)

Any help/advice please?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The first positional argument to the `update_status()` method is interpreted as the [`media_ids` parameter](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update#api-param-media_ids). You need to explicitly name your `status` parameter to avoid this:

```
api.update_status(status=single_tweet)
```

This is a [recent change](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/commit/f99b1da52aecdeaedb75d23390c41f0865ed4b81) in Tweepy and it looks like their [documentation](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html#API.update_status) hasn't been updated yet to reflect this.

The different signature has been [reported as a bug](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/554) for the project.

The bug was fixed in August 2015; version 3.5 or newer of Tweepy once again treat the first positional argument as the `status` parameter.